# Select rows based on date and time range

Tags: sql-server, spring, hibernate, jpa, jodatime

I am querying a table based on two columns date and time to return the rows:
`tx_creation_date [date]` and `tx_creation_time [time(7)]`

With the following query statement:

```
public interface PurchaseRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Purchase, BigDecimal> { 

    @Query(value = "select p from Purchase p where (p.txCreationDate >= 
    :startDate and p.txCreationTime >= :startTime) and (p.txCreationDate <= :endDate and p.txCreationTime <= :endTime)")  
    public List<Purchase> findAllTxByTimestampRange(@Param(startDate) LocalDate startDate,  
    @Param(startTime) LocalTime startTime, @Param(endDate) LocaleDate endDate,  
    @Param(endTime) LocalTime endTime);  

    other queries...  
}
```

Here is a snippet of the Purchase class:

```
@Entity  
@Table(name = "po_log")  
public class Purchase implements Serializable {  
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1L;  

    @Id  
    @Column(name = "po_number")
    private BigDecimal poNumber;  

    private String type;  

    @Column(name = "tx_creation_date")  
    @Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalDate")  
    private LocalDate txCreationDate;  

    @Column(name = "tx_creation_time")
    @Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersitentLocalTime")  
    private LocalTime txCreationTime; 

    ..  
    .. 

    getters and setters  

}
```

Upon execution I got the following error message:

> The data types datetime and time are incompatible in the greater than or equal to operator

I've tried couple tricks with no success:

1. Setting this `sendTimeAsDateTime=false` in the connection properties
2. Use of `cast (txCreationTime as time)` or `convert`
3. Use of `cast` to concatenate date and time as `datetime`

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Sidenote:**  Selecting rows with date range only yield to success. Therefore the issue truly lies in time.

*My current setup*:

- Spring annotations
- Hibernate 4
- Jadira for user types and Joda for LocalDate and LocalTime
- SQL Server 2014
- localDate from user formatted to yyyyMMdd
- localTime from user formatted to HHmmssSSS

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `jtds` driver - try to use native [microsft JDBC driver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server) - it implements JDBC 4 and should work properly with time.

Or, you can map time column in yours entity as `String` and set params in query like `new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss.SSS")`

Comment: I am using microsoft JDBC 6 driver already and tried out version 4 just to be thorough. no luck. So I switched to native query. Anyway thank you for your input.